# MATLAB function sparse to python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I have to convert these MATLAB lines to python. I don't know how exacly to do this, what I know is that I should use `csr_matrix` from `scipy.sparse`.

```
A = sparse(Nx,Nx);
A = A + sparse([1 Nx],[1 Nx],[1 1],Nx,Nx);
A = A + sparse(2:Nx-1,2:Nx-1,ones(Nx-2,1)*(1+2*r),Nx,Nx);
A = A - sparse(2:Nx-1,1:Nx-2,ones(Nx-2,1)*r,Nx,Nx);
A = A - sparse(2:Nx-1,3:Nx,ones(Nx-2,1)*r,Nx,Nx);
```

I tried something like this:

```
A = sp.csr_matrix((Nx,Nx), dtype=np.float)
A = A + sp.csr_matrix((z,(x,y)), shape=(Nx,Nx), dtype=np.float)
```

But I don't know what to put in this x,y,z positions:

```
Nx=1000 and r=99.8001
```

Comment: The MATLAB `S = sparse(i,j,v,m,n)` syntax is close to the `scipy` `S = sparse.csc_matrix((v, (i,j)), shape=(m,n))`, where `v` is the data, and `i,j` are row and column index arrays.  Practice with some small matrices till you get a feel for the equivalence.

Comment: Yes, I know, but when I trying to do it in this example I can't manage.. Could u tell me how to write this "A = A + sparse([1 Nx],[1 Nx],[1 1],Nx,Nx);" in python, that would help me a lot.